# How do I set up with Heroku's new eco dynos?

Tags: node.js, heroku, strapi, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to upload a Strapi app to Heroku. I am able to see my app on the dashboard and can click on it and view a welcome message. I have entered my credit card number and selected the 'eco dynos'.

I am following instructions in the Strapi docs. The
specific line I am having trouble with is:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

`hobby-dev` no longer exists I have tried replacing `hobby-dev` with `eco-dynos`, and a number of other variations but all I get is the message:

```
Creating heroku-postresql:eco-dynos on ⬢ 
ltdjeventsbackend... ! !    Couldn't find either 
the add-on service or the add-on
 !    plan of "heroku-postresql:eco-dynos".
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hobby-dev` in that command doesn't refer to the dyno type, but rather to [the Heroku Postgres plan](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#pricing) you wish to provision. `hobby-dev` is still listed on the addon page, though I believe [that will change in a few days](https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter), on November 28, 2022.

The equivalent of "eco" (the cheapest non-free tier for dynos) for Heroku Postgres is "mini". I'm seeing it at $0.01 per month right now, but [I believe it's meant to cost $5](https://blog.heroku.com/new-low-cost-plans). This may flip in the documentation after the 28th.

Try this:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:mini
```